# In Windows 8 Metro (WinRT) and C#/XAML, what's the best practice to implement flowing item results (i.e., continuous paging)?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm writing a Windows 8 Metro app in C#/XAML.

One of the core functions is to call out to a JSON API and display thumbnail results.  I've got that working, but the JSON API is a paged-based API, so I can fetch the first page of 25 results, the next page of 25 results, and so on.  On some queries, there are thousands and thousands of results, and I'd like the user to be able to swipe through them, flow-style.

What's the best-practice way to implement continuous results, where I swipe to the right or down and it auto-fills, similar to viewing images on Pinterest?

Is there a dedicated control that does this, or do I embed some kind of listener control and watch its visible state, or something else?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sounds like reactive extensions would help?

Comment: Perhaps a solution involves inserting items into a list control, and then adding a marker link maybe 75% of the way through the loaded list, and watching its IsVisibleChanged event on the UIElement?  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged.aspx

Comment: @user61307 IsVisibleChanged does not exist in WinRT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're collection needs to implement ISupportIncrementalLoading. The strategy for handling this scenario changed from the developer preview. I can't find any examples of using this interface in the consumer preview but there is one that targets the developer preview on the [metro forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e71b7036-4fb7-4963-a65d-5bcb9fd8f664).

Answer (score 1):

Create a ListBox and set its ItemPanel to StackPanel which is ordered horizontally. Then bind ListBox's ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection which keeps your thumbnails. Write a function that populates this ObservableCollection and call this function from somewhere asynchronously with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

Comment: But how do I seamlessly (and appropriately) load the 2nd and 3rd and 4th page of results... ?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is not about having a lot of loaded items then you can query the total number of results on your JSON API then create all the items, and asynchronously call a Load method that fills their data.

This will give you empty tiles until data is loaded and will progressively show more and more tiles.

A few thousand items in a listbox should work flawlessly.

I've seen a demo with 1000 and there were no problems.